# Laravel: Auth::user()->id Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

i'm Getting an error 'Trying to get property 'name' of non-object ' when i Trying to open dashboard page

[image]

There is my codes :

in **UserController.php**

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    $result = User::orderBy('name','asc')->get();
    return view('admin.user.index',[ 'data'=>$result ]);
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you just output `Auth::user()` to the page?

Comment: actually the problem is not  here  the problem is in your blade file you are trying to access without auth user   because it is returning null can you show us your full usercontroller php code

Comment: @MohammadUsman there my UserController php code
link : https://pastebin.com/scwy3hQF

Comment: try this and tell me what are you getting from it  ```dd(Auth::user()->name);```  and add this  ```class UserController extends Controller
{ public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    
}```